Recent update to Ubuntu 24.04 is disrupting my mouse and keyboard
  OS: Ubuntu 24.04
  GNOME version: 46
  Windowing system: Wayland
  Kernel version: Linux 6.8.0-40-generic
After my Ubuntu updated itself yesterday, and I restarted my laptop today to install the new update at first my mouse was shaking and then froze for like 15 minutes. I power shutdown the laptop by holding down the power button, then when I turned on my laptop again, my mouse stopped working.
I can't control it, but I can move my mouse with the red thing at the keyboard area. After I went to get an external mouse, I was enjoying the mouse for like 36 minutes and then my laptop moved to autopilot. I don't know what is going on, but it looked like it was an AI controlling my laptop. It can literally do anything from opening my browser, restoring tab, bookmarking some tab, closing my browser, etc.
I forcefully tried to open the System Monitor, but it keeps disrupting me. Please who else is facing this challenges or have I been hacked? Or how can I downgrade my Ubuntu version without losing my laptop folders? I really need help urgently, because I have a project that has a looming deadline that is very close.
I have restarted my system for more than 3 times now.

This could be caused by either a hardware or a software problem. For starters what happens if you use a different mouse?

What make and model of mouse? Is it a wired mouse or wireless/bluetooth?

it is working fine now after I suspended instead of restarting (which I have done multiple times). it got back to normal since yesterday, sorry for the late feedback.
